# How to modify the url automatically if browser is from asia?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

How to achieve following scenario?
I want to modify the url when browser is from Asia. When I will hit url with domain my.XXX.com then, the application will check the browser location and if the browser is from asia then, it will automatically change url with domain to asia.XXX.com.

Thanks

Comment: Where - in the client side or the server side? You'll need to do an IP geolocation look up first, or for a broad-brush you could query whois to see if APNIC own the block, and then a redirect. Which part of this do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Right thing to do on the server side, defining the country by IP (GEOIP).

It is also possible to learn the language of the preset browser.

JQuery
`$.browserLanguage(function( language , acceptHeader ){
    alert("You have your browser language set to " + language);
})`

or native
`var lng = navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
alert(lng);`